# Does Euler's Formula prove all imaginary numbers equal $0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Euler's formula is

$$ e^{i \theta } = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta $$

If we take $\theta$ to be $2 \pi$ we get

$$e^{2i \pi} = \cos (2 \pi ) + i \sin (2 \pi ) $$

Which simplifies to

$$e^{2i \pi} = 1$$

But we also know

$$e^0 = 1$$

Therefore, can we not say

$$e^0 = e^{2i \pi}$$

and thus,

$$0 = 2i \pi$$

Which leads to being a big problem for all imaginary numbers.

Example with $25i$:

$$\begin{align}
25i &= \frac{25 (2 \pi) i}{2 \pi} \\
25i &= \frac{25 * 0}{2 \pi} \\
25i &= 0 \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: If $a,\,b$ are real numbers then $e^a=e^b$ if and only if $a=b$, however, this is not true if $a,\,b$ are complex numbers.

Comment: What if instead of exponentials, we just considered some arbitrary function. If $f(a)=f(b)$, can we say that $a=b$? No, because there may be multiple values that map to $f(a)$ (such as $a,b,...$).

Comment: First displayed equation is incorrect. Surely you mean $i\theta$ instead of $1\theta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot say $e^{0}=e^{2\pi i}$ implies $0=2\pi i$.

The map $z\mapsto e^{z}$ is not one-to-one in the complex numbers.

Comment: Fun fact, an easter egg from the God: it holds that $0 = 1 + e^{i\pi}$. All magical numbers in one equation: 0, 1, e, i, $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

The correct conclusion of
$$e^a=e^b$$ is not that $a=b$, but rather that $a=b+2k\pi i$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.